# How to access Tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, networking, tortoisesvn

I am using 6 PC's in my office. I have to connect them with svn Tortoise svn but after making repository in my D: drive, I don't know how to connect 6 PC's to one another and how to make my one PC a server. I am installing the tortoise software in every 6 PC. Should I create a repository on each PC or just one PC? I am also aware that I have to make username and password but I did not know where to set password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Tortoise is not a bad idea for your job. Installing Tortoise on all PCs was also correct.

Now you need **one** repository (not one on each pc). The repository can be created via `context menu -> TortoiseSVN -> create repository here`. At this point you have to make sure that all PC can access this repository. Use file sharing function of your operating system.

After that create a trunk (your codebase) in you repository.

Finally get the trunk to all of you PCs via `context menu -> TortoiseSVN ->  Checkout`.

*This is a short description of thinks to do. If you you need help in detail please feel free to ask.*